# How to slot specific setting for a slot that is being swapped

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webapps

I have a preprod slot on azure web app that is swapped to production slot.
It has same configuration that production slot will have except redirectUrl.
I am using azure devops pipelines to automate the process.

I need the redirectUrl in prepod slot to have different value to verify application working before swapping.

How to have a slot specific setting for a slot that is being swapped to another slot?
I want to avoid one setting being swapped.

Comment: Hi @Khalil, is there answer below about make the setting not swappable helps? If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the settings that change when you swap slots.

Settings that are swapped:

[image]

Settings that aren't swapped:

[image]

To configure an app setting or connection string to stick to a specific slot (not swapped), go to the Configuration page for that slot. Add or edit a setting, and then select deployment slot setting. Selecting this check box tells App Service that the setting is not swappable. You could also refer to [Which settings are swapped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#which-settings-are-swapped) for more information.

[image]